# Don't get the url contains: "togl" [Regex]

Tags: php, regex, url

I have a great URL catching Regex but I have a problem.. I don't want to catch url's from are togl.me... My Regexp is:

```
(?i)\b((?:https?://|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'\".,<>?«»“”‘’]))
```

And this is the regex pattern:

```
(?xi)
\b
(                       # Capture 1: entire matched URL
  (?:
    https?://               # http or https protocol
    |                       #   or
    www\d{0,3}[.]           # "www.", "www1.", "www2." … "www999."
    |                           #   or
    [a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/  # looks like domain name followed by a slash
  )
  (?:                       # One or more:
    [^\s()<>]+                  # Run of non-space, non-()<>
    |                           #   or
    \(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)  # balanced parens, up to 2 levels
  )+
  (?:                       # End with:
    \(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)  # balanced parens, up to 2 levels
    |                               #   or
    [^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?«»“”‘’]        # not a space or one of these punct chars
  )
)
```

Don't catch URLs from http://togl.me . I can check the domain name with parse_url after catching the URLs but why need it?

Comment: What's wrong with [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)?

Comment: NullUserException, after nearly three years, I see that your reply is completely correct. Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

After matching the domain, you can look back to check that it was not `togl.me`.

```
[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}(?<!/togl\.me)/
```

---

**Edit:** since the domain can be matched in other places than where the comments say so, lets move the check for `togl.me`.

```
…
    [a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/  # looks like domain name followed by a slash
  )
  (?<!togl\.me/) 
  (?!togl\.me)
  (?:                       # One or more:
    [^\s()<>]+
…
```

More help: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: Ah, your regex sucks! `togl.me` urls are still matched by the `http://`+`non-space` parts.

Comment: I have one more question, this regex doesn't work with JavaScript/Client side.. Can you again help me for this problem, too?

Comment: @Oral ÜNAL, No. Ask a new question and tag it with the appropriate programming language tag.